# Joomla | enabling SEF removes index.php, but returns a 404 page. Page visible thru index.php/page. How to fix?

Tags: joomla-sef-urls

I'm running Joomla 2.5.8 and I'm trying to delete the stupid index.php so having SEO friendly URLs. Yet.. When enabled and rebuild' the menu, when I click on a menu item the site goes to the page without the /index.php/ BUT it returns a 404 page. However, when I manually type /index.php/ between the domain and the page, I see the normal page.

A few notes

> I changed htaccess.txt to .htaccess
>
> ```
> I removed the '#' before RewriteBase /
>
> I added 'cms' to the directory path (RewriteBase /cms ) Since Joomla is in the /cms folder
>
> However, the htaccess is in the SAME folder as Joomla itself, they both lie in a subfolder
>
> In the root folder, where a different website is stored, there also lies a .htaccess file
> ```

Any suggestions guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your config is OK.
The htaccess with RewriteBase /CMS, should be in the /CMS folder.
In Joomla you should have sef rules enabled and use mod_rewrite option enabled.

This could simply be a cache clearing issue.

Comment: One other thing I forgot, you should also configure the LiveSite entry in your configuration.php.  I've found this helps on certain sites, the criteria for which I haven't managed to figure out yet.